# Changes to Core Graphics in iOS9/Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift2, ios9

What are the changes made to the CoreGraphics framework in iOS 9? A couple of libraries which do not support Swift 2.0 yet show this -

`Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGPathStroke'`

Comment: Would be better to point out the mistakes/edits required to make the question sound rather than just downvoting it

Comment: I am also curious about this. Not sure why kCGPathStroke throws an error in swift 2, but it's certainly a problem and I can't find any answers about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Swift 2.0, CoreGraphics constants became Enums.

Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGPathDrawingMode

So now you should use: `CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke` or just `.Stroke` instead of `kCGPathStroke`.